# Anydesk ubuntu not forwarding ctrl and super keys

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard-shortcuts, remote-desktop, anydesk

I've installed Anydesk on both my laptop and remote PC. Both have ubuntu 18.04. While everything else works fine, Anydesk doesn't transmit `ctrl` and `super` keys. So, if I press `super`, it opens all programs on my laptop and not on the remote desktop. Similarly, if I press `ctrl+a`, it only transmits the character `a`. This is causing a lot of problems for me since I'm used to keyboard shortcuts and a lot of them depend on `ctrl`.

**Edit 1**:
If I connect from another windows laptop to Ubuntu remote, `ctrl+a` works. So, it must be some problem with my local Anydesk.

Comment: Have you checked the option "forward key combinations"?

Comment: Yes. Other key combinations like `shift+A` works

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured out the problem and fixed it. The problem is not with Anydesk but with Ubuntu. I have installed Gnome tweaks and enabled "show mouse pointer position on pressing ctrl" So, when I press ctrl, instead of sending it to the remote desktop, ubuntu consumes the key by itself and only the other key goes to remote desktop. So, when I press `ctrl+a`, only `a` is forwarded to remote desktop. Somehow TeamViewer handles this i.e. send `ctrl` key also to remote desktop.

Note: I figured this by trying chrome remote desktop and the problem repeated with that as well. Then I figured out that the problem is with Ubuntu and not Anydesk

Comment: Well it is a problem with Anydesk too, isn't it? Remmina has this option to "grab all keyboard events" and it is working perfectly.

Comment: You're right. Since TeamViewer and Remmina handle this, it's a drawback of Anydesk. Anyway, what I meant by "problem not with Anydesk" was that it was not due to some incorrect setting in local Anydesk installation.

Comment: I same issue and solution in Pop!_OS or Pop OS. Posting a comment for others to find via search.